# The specified field 'ID' could refer to more than one table

Tags: c#, oledbconnection

I keep getting this error when I try to find by ID:

> system.data.oledb.oledbexception the speciefied field 'ID' could refer
>   to more than one table listed in the FROM clause of your SQL Statement

Here's my code:

```
public static Invoice GetInvoice(string id)
    {
        OleDbConnection conn = GetConnection();
        Invoice invoice = null;
        if (conn == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        string sqlString = "SELECT * FROM Person INNER JOIN Employee ON " +
            "Person.ID=Employee.ID WHERE ID = @ID";
        OleDbCommand comm = new OleDbCommand(sqlString, conn);
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", id);
        OleDbDataReader dr = null;
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            dr = comm.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SingleRow);
            if (dr.Read())
            {
                invoice = new Invoice();
                invoice.PersonID = (string)dr["ID"];
                invoice.FirstName = (string)dr["FirstName"];
                invoice.LastName = (string)dr["LastName"];
                invoice.Age = (int)dr["Age"];
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            invoice = null;
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
        return invoice;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your query, at the moment you're selecting a wildcard '*', which means it will pull both the Persons ID and the Employee ID, but wont have a unique reference. Change your wildcard to pull the exact tables ID like below:

`SELECT Person.ID, FirstName, LastName FROM...`

You will also need to change your WHERE statement to something like:

```
WHERE Person.ID = @ID
```

as the where statement doesnt know which tables ID to filter on (i know they're the same values, but SQL doesnt care about that)

Comment: Don't forget the where clause.